# Does reindexing an infinite series change its value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm wondering if reindexing a divergent or conditionally convergent infinite series changes the value of the series. Specifically, if we have a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ that is either divergent or conditionally convergent, does rearranging the terms by reindexing the series (e.g. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1}$ or $\sum_{n=17}^{\infty} a_{n-16}$) change the final value of the series?

I would assume such a change in index holds true (probably by Riemann Rearrangement Theorem). But I'm not sure if this holds for divergent or conditionally convergent series. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Your "reindexing" doesn't really change the partial sum sequence in any way, so the sum would not change. To change the value of the infinite sum, you have to actually permute the order of the terms.

Answer (score 2):

If you write out the summations by putting down the first few terms in order followed by an ellipsis ... you will see that the expressions are the same. In all cases you see just
$$
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots .
$$

(That is often a useful strategy when looking at sums.)